# How to send Algolia events in a React Native app?

Tags: react-native, algolia

I need to send search events to Algolia from a react native app. The closest I got was to find the search-insights package from algolia, but there isn't any documentation on how to properly use it in a React Native app.

Anybody did this before that can point me in the right direction?

Comment: havent used before but if you looking for searching only react instantsearch might work

Answer (score 1):

Algolia just published some guides about how to use it with react-native i.e. https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/building-search-ui/going-further/native/react-hooks/ and https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/building-search-ui/going-further/native/react/